# Share View between apps

Tags: android, layout, view, share, interactive

The first, Sorry about my bad English. I am developing interactive app which can update view(UI) in an app from another app. 
Can you tell me How to share View/Layout from an app to another app? 
Please any suggestion.
Thanks !!!

Comment: please explain about your requirements

Comment: Example : I have two apps : A & B . I click button on app A, it send a broadcast to B , says B updates view (depend on data A send B). Now i use json for transfer, but it's too long, and not clear. Another way ?

Comment: okay, if i understood your requirement you have app a running on your device and when you click on any button within app a you want app b to launch  isn't it since even if you update any thing to app b it won't be visible until app b launches?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I mean, App A send data (json, view, anything...) to app B, and app B update view (Ex : Show 1 question and 4 optional answer) with that data. I don't want use json.So, Do you have any fast way to transfer and update view on app B.

Comment: I edited my answer to include advice about sending layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do, I assume you want to launch App B after a Button in App A is clicked and give App B some kind of information. Doing this is no problem with Intents. I don't really know what kind of data you are trying to send, but since it seems that the data is a little more complex I will send a serializable object in this example but you can send pretty much any kind of data. For a more detailed documentation refer to the Android Guidelines on Intents:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

First the Object you want to send needs to implement Serializable:

```
public class DataContainer implements Serializable {
     ...
}
```

Here's the OnClickListener from App A which starts App B:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        // The Object you are trying to send
        DataContainer container = getData(); 

        // Create the Intent to start the other App
        Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.android.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

        // Add the object to the Intent. With the String "Data" you can later retrieve the Object in the other App
        intent.putExtra("Data", container);

        // Start the other App
        context.startActivity(intent);
     }   
});
```

In App B's main Activity in the onCreate method you can retrieve the Object:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // This means you only retrieve the data on the first start of the App, not after an orientation change etc.
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {

        // Get the Intent the App was started with.
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // Retrieve the Object you wanted to send to this App.
        DataContainer data = (DataContainer) intent.getSerializableExtra("Data");
    }
}
```

In this example I use the String "Data" as a tag to attach the object to the Intent. Never hardcode a String like that in a real app. You should define a constant for that purpose.

**Edit:**

If you want to send a layout I would simply send the ressource id, like this:

In App A:

```
int resId = R.layout.layout_to_send;
intent.putExtra("layout", resId);
```

In App B:

```
int resId = intent.getIntExtra("layout", -1);
...
if(resId >= 0) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resId, parent, false);
    ...
}
```

Anyway I would not recommend doing this. If you do something like this, you send information to another app which has nothing to do with this app, which by design should be independent from each other. Consider instead something like this:

Create an enum with all possible Actions the other app is supposed to do.

```
public enum Action {
    SHOW_VIEW_A,
    SHOW_VIEW_B,
    ...
}
```

Add it to the intent in App A:

```
intent.putExtra("action", Action.SHOW_VIEW_A);
```

In App B react to each possible case.

```
Action action = intent.getSerializableExtra("action");

View view = null;
switch(action) {
    case SHOW_VIEW_A:
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_a, parent, false);
        break;

    case SHOW_VIEW_B:
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_b, parent, false);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

if(view != null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sr, i didn't explain clearly about my problem. Can I send a layout ?

Comment: Well yes, if App B already contains the layout you only have to send the resource id. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I 'll try on your way.And let you know result.